# split string and type error issue

Tags: python, regex

I am trying split line using regular expression and write new file with delimitated format.

```
import re,sys

with open('raw.txt', 'rb') as f:
    s = f.read()
    result = re.split('\s+(\d+)\s+', s.split('n'))
    print result
```

However, I keep getting the 'expected string or buffer' error. I tried to run this code using test file which is not goo large, it works well. But I guess my raw file is too large (> 20000 rows) so read() may cause memory issue.

So, I tried to use f.readlines() like that:

```
 f = open('raw.txt', 'r') 
 for line in f.readlines():
     result = re.split('\s+(\d+)\s+', line)
     print result
```

But it did not work well. Can anybody help? Thank you!

FYI, my raw file looks like that:

```
f = open('raw.txt', 'r')
dline = f.readlines()
dline 
['Alcoholic liver disease 7124    TNF\n', 'Alcoholic liver disease 3557    IL1RN\n', 'Alcoholic liver disease 929     CD14\n', 'Alopecia        3572    IL6ST\n', 'Alopecia        3976    LIF\n', 'Alopecia        1489    CTF1\n', "Alzheimer's disease     5300    PIN1\n", "Alzheimer's disease     6667    SP1\n", "Alzheimer's disease     3316    HSPB2\n", "Alzheimer's disease     3320    HSP90AA1\n", "Alzheimer's disease     8851    CDK5R1\n", 'Aseptic necrosis of bone        302     ANXA2\n', 'Aseptic necrosis of bone        1499    CTNNB1\n', 'Aseptic necrosis of bone        2147    F2\n', 'Aseptic necrosis of bone        2153    F5\n', 'Aseptic necrosis of bone        5054    SERPINE1\n']
so, what I want to make new file looks like that:
results ## string+'\t'+ integer + '\t' + string +'\n'
['Alcoholic liver disease', '7124', 'TNF\nAlcoholic liver disease', '3557', 'IL1RN\nAlcoholic liver disease', '929', 'CD14\nAlopecia', '3572', 'IL6ST\nAlopecia', '3976', 'LIF\nAlopecia', '1489', "CTF1\nAlzheimer's disease", '5300', "PIN1\nAlzheimer's disease", '6667',
```

Comment: Any chance of a clearer problem statement than *"it did not work well"*?

Comment: What do you mean by "it did not work well"? By the way, you probably meant `s.split('\n')` in your first version; i.e., you want to split by the new-line character rather than the letter 'n'.

Comment: It would be more useful to include a small sample of your text file in the question, rather than the output of some python commands to read it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternatively,

```
 f = open('raw.txt', 'r') 
 for line in f.readlines():
     result = line.rsplit()
     print result
```

Hope this helps.